# Probability device indicates fault of short and open circuit

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Circuit boards from a production line are screened for circuit faults using an automated testing device indicates which does not distinguish between different types of fault. when a short circuit is present, the device indicates a fault 96% of the time, and when an open circuit is present, the device indicates a fault 89% of the time. However, it also indicated that a fault is present for 3% of the boards which do not have a fault.

a) Previous quality control investigations have shown that 4% of the circuit boards from this production line have short circuits and 6% have open circuits. Assuming that none of the boards have both an open circuit and a short circuit, calculate the probability that the device indicates a fault when testing a randomly chosen circuit board.
b) Hence determine the probability that a circuit board which is marked as faulty by the testing device actually has a short circuit.

Comment: so both open and short circuits constitute a fault?

Comment: thats the question, answer for (a) is 0.118 (b)0.3232

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general directions. Denote $F$ the event of a fault, $F_1$ short circuit, $F_2$ the open circuit, $G$ means good. 
$$
P(F)=P(F|F_1)P(F_1) +P(F|F_2)P(F_2) + P(F|G)P(G)
$$
You are given all four values on the RHS, so you can find $P(F)$. Use it to find the conditional 
$$
P(F_1|F)=\frac{P(F|F_1)P(F_1)}{P(F)}
$$

Can you handle from here?